# Renaming the name of a field in a View

Tags: views

I've set up a View which displays the latest posts of a custom content type. Its fields are the usual, such as image, summary and title.

Though I would like the name of title that the View displays to be different than the original.

So for example the name of the title in the content type is **Location of Project**. Rather, I would like to have the View title only display **Location**. The titles' output would continue to show the same information, for example **Canada**.

Couldn't find a way to achieve this using the Views config. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in Field configuration to **Create a label**. It's usually just at the top of the options.

You have to tick it to enable it. Once you tick it an input field appears where you can enter a different label for your field.

To get to the field configuration just click on the desired field under `Fields` area in your Views.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot that the reason the title was being shown in the first place was because I had **Use field template** ticked.